# Why does QGIS Simplify Geometries delete entire polygons?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am reducing the size of a world timezone shapefile,

http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/tz_world_mp.zip

But at a 0.01 tolerance, entire countries disappear

Anybody know a way round this?

QGIS shows the same error simplifying naturalearthdatamaps also; simplify with 0.01 tolerance and Italy disappears

Comment: beta, but worth a try http://kelsocartography.com/downloads/gis/2012/natural_earth/ne_10m_time_zones_beta_3.zip

Comment: Shafefile is hard to reuse and is missing timezones, good start though

Comment: Can anybody recommend alternate tool to simplify geometry and reduce size of shapefile?

Comment: Check related questions such as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178/simplifying-adjacent-polygons & http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3739/generalisation-strategies-for-building-outlines. If you cannot find an answer that works in your case, please open a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a known problem http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4189

> The reason for wrong behavior is a tiny ring. If it is removed, the polygon is simplified ok. The polygons with bigger rings simplify ok, but if any polygon has a ring that is smaller than tolerance, it breaks the whole polygon.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Well found. Looks like I need to ogr2ogr until the fix the bug in QGIS

Comment: I have tried GRASS and openjump on the timezone shapefile. The first simplifies but does not reduce filesize, the second crashes on an error. In order to progress, I am happy to contract help, anybody interested?

Comment: mapshaper.com/test/MapShaper.swf simplifies shapefiles, and is robust to ocurrence of polygon rings smaller than the simplify tolerance.